# Find series expansion of $\log^{\alpha}(1-x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

We know that
$$\log(1-x) = - \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{x^n}n; \quad 0<x<1.$$
I would like to know what the series expansion of
 $$\log^{\alpha}(1-x)=?\, \mbox{or}\, \log^{\alpha}(\frac{1}{1-x})=?\,; \, \mbox{for}\quad 0<x<1 \, \mbox{and}\, -1<\alpha<0.$$

Thank you in advance

Comment: $\log^\alpha$ is the logarithm applied $\alpha$ times? Or is $\alpha$ a power? I would assume the latter, since $\alpha \in (-1,0)$.

Comment: I would just say $\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\right)^\alpha$.  If you really wished, you could attempt to apply mult-nomial expansion to the thing after that, or maybe Taylor's theorem.

Comment: $\alpha$ is a power ($-1<\alpha<0$).

Comment: @SimpleArt  $z^\alpha$ doesn't have a power series expansion around $z =0$, so $(\log(1-x))^\alpha$ doesn't have a power series expansion around $x = 0$

Comment: now if you consider the branch where $\log(1) = 2 i \pi$, you get $(2 i \pi + x)^a = (2i \pi)^{-a}(1+\frac{x}{2 i \pi})^a = (2i \pi)^{-a}\sum_{k=0}^\infty {k \choose a} (\frac{x}{2 i \pi})^k$ for $|x| < 2 \pi$, so for $|x| < 1$ and $|\ln(1-x)| < 2\pi$ : $(\ln(1-x))^a = (2 i \pi)^{-a}\sum_{k=0}^\infty {k \choose a} (\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n})^k (2 i \pi)^{-k}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling-Zahl look for "Stirling-Polynome" (Stirling polynomials)
you have to scroll down a bit, it's $\displaystyle(\frac{-\ln(1-t)}{t})^x$

Comment: But in my case $-1<\alpha<0$

Comment: @Z.Alfata That's fine too.

Comment: @Z. Alfata : A few lines below there is the formula for the polynom $\psi_k(x)$. You see that your case is no problem.

Comment: @Z. Alfata : You are welcome.

Comment: See directly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_polynomials